# Typescript filter two array of objects

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-filters

I have to objects where I need to filter out the data that exists in one but not the other

For example Object 1

```
0:Object {Name: "Java", ResourceCount: 3}
1:Object {Name: "DotNet", ResourceCount: 4}
2:Object {Name: "Hadoop", ResourceCount: 1}
3:Object {Name: "Pega", ResourceCount: 2}
4:Object {Name: "Oracle", ResourceCount: 1}
5:Object {Name: "ETL", ResourceCount: 1}
```

Object 2

```
0:"DotNet"
1:"ETL"
2:"Hadoop"
3:"Java"
4:"Oracle"
5:"Pega"
6:"Mainframe"
```

I need to return "MainFrame" from object 2 since it does not exist in object 1.

This is what I have tried so far to no avail.

```
  const filteredList = object2.filter(item1 => 
          object1.find(item2 => item1.Name != item2.Name));
```

all this does is return all of the rows in object 2

Comment: `item2` doesn't have `.Name` property, since it's just a plain string. You need `item1.Name == item2` - flip the check, too, since otherwise you'll always get `true` since there is always at least one item where the name doesn't match. You can also swap `.find` for `.some` to be a bit more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, create an array of names to help filter the object2; (array2)
I have joined the results with a , if multiple names exist

```js
let object1 = [{Name: "Java", ResourceCount: 3}, {Name: "DotNet", ResourceCount: 4}, {Name: "Hadoop", ResourceCount: 1}, {Name: "Pega", ResourceCount: 2}, {Name: "Oracle", ResourceCount: 1}, {Name: "ETL", ResourceCount: 1}]
let object2 = ["DotNet", "ETL", "Hadoop", "Java", "Oracle", "Pega", "Mainframe"]

let object1Names = object1.map(obj => obj.Name); // for caching the result
results = object2.filter(name => !object1Names.includes(name)).join(',');
console.log(results);
```